# CSS ie6 hover issue

Tags: css, hover, internet-explorer-6

I am pretty sure everyone knows the hover issue in IE6.
I tried to fix the problem by using "csshoverfix.htc" or "whatever:hover". I downloaded it from the writer's page, and ofcourse I added

```
body { behavior:url("csshover.htc"); }
```

to my css file, But it didnt help.
I also tried to use jquery hover function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#autoSuggestionsList li').hover(
    function(){
        alert("test");
    },
    function(){
        alert("test");
    })
});
```

But also it didnt work.
I dont know if it can be the reason why it doesnt work, but the `<li>` with the hover, are made in real time (ajax).

anyway, how can I fix the hover issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I dont know if it can be the reason why it doesnt work, but the `<li>` with the hover, are made in real time (ajax).

Possibly. Try using [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live) instead so that it works with elements that come from Ajax responses:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#autoSuggestionsList li').live(
    {
        mouseover: function() {
            alert("test");
        },
        mouseout: function() {
            alert("test");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This is correct - the original code, as it stood, would only search the DOM at document.ready time and apply all the hover events, any new nodes added later would not have them applied. Alternatively, extract the `$('#autoSuggestionsList li').hover()` code to its own function, and call it during the callback of the ajax function. That might be a better way to do it, because live events can be resource-hogging.

Comment: Yup, it did the job. Thank you very much!.